# Convergence of a certain series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $(q_n)$ is an enumeration of rationals in $(-1,1)$ except $0$, is the following series convergent?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(nq_n)^2}
$$

Are there enumerations for which is convergent and enumerations for which is divergent?

I accidentally asked this question on mathoverflow. If anyone is on both sites, please delete it there. I did not sign up for an account, and I did not know how to erase it myself.

Comment: Is it convergent if you only use positive rationals? Not entirely obvious.

Comment: An example where it diverges was provided on mathoverflow, where I mistakenly posted it first.

Comment: @StefanSmith It was not a complete answer. The more interesting part was when it converges.

Comment: @Timur : sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to provide an example wherein $q_n \ge h(n)=(1/8)n^{-1/3},$ a slight adjustment of the idea in roger's answer. The factor $1/8$ was inserted just so one could start out the sequence. If this is done, then $1/(nq_n)^2 \le 64/n^{4/3}$ which converges when summed.

Note that $h(n)$ is decreasing, and $h(8^k)=1/2^{k+1}.$
Begin with an enumeration $r_1,r_2,\cdots$ of the rationals in $(0,1)$. We will describe $q_n$ as a rearrangement of the sequence of $r_j$ by a definite rule.

Step $0$: Take $q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_{2^3}$ as the first eight terms of the $r$ sequence (in their order from that sequence) which are at least $1/2^3.$ Since $h(1)=1/2^3$ and $h$ is decreasing, each $q_j$ is at least $h(j)$ in this first step.

Step $1$: Take $q_{2^3+1},\cdots, q_{2^6}$ as the first $2^6-2^3$ terms of the $r$ sequence not already chosen on step $0$ which are at least $1/2^4$. Since $h(2^3)=1/2^4$ and $h$ is decreasing, each $q_j$ chosen in step 1 is at least $h(j)$.

Each further step ("step $t$") selects another block of the sequence of $q$'s from an index $2^{3t}+1$ through index $2^{3(t+1)}$, and uses the next terms of the $r$ sequence which are at least $1/2^{t+1}$.

Every $r_j$ in the initial list of rationals must eventually get used, since once it becomes available on step $t$ it remains available on all further steps. Then since $r_j$ has a definite position in the initial sequence $r_1,r_2,\cdots$ it will eventually get chosen on some step $t$.

So this gives an example of such a sequence which is convergent. It is not directly constructive, unless one views the initial sequence of $r's$ as constructive, and the rearrangement process.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume to simplify and WLOG that you only consider the rationals in $(0,1)$. The series is convergent for instance if you take $q_n \geq n^{-1/3}$ for all $n$. It is divergent is you take $q_{2n} \leq \frac 1 {n} $ for all $n$.

Comment: True, but you might want to provide an example of the enumeration of the rationals satisfying the first condition.

Comment: sorry, I cannot parse this.

Comment: At this point I tend to agree with Igor, it is not clear to me how to build an enumeration satisfying the first condition.