# Convergence of a certain series - part II

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My question is related to [Convergence of a certain series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597139/convergence-of-a-certain-series)

Let $(q_n)_n$ be an enumeration of rationals in $(0,1)$. Can we always find $x\in(0,1)$ such that the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2(q_n-x)^2}
$$
is convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the sequence $(q_{2n})$ enumerates the dyadic rationals $(2i+1)2^{-j}$ in $(0,1)$ following the lexicographic order on $(j,i)$ and that the sequence $(q_{2n+1})$ enumerates the other rationals. The beginning of the sequence $(q_{2n})$ is $1/2,1/4,3/4,1/8,3/8,5/8,7/8,1/16,3/16\ldots$ hence the rationals $(2i+1)2^{-j}$ are the entries $q_{2n}$ for $2^{j-1}\leqslant n\lt2^j$.

Let $x$ in $(0,1)$. For every $j\geqslant1$, there exists some $i$ such that $|x-(2i+1)2^{-j}|\leqslant2^{-j}$. This rational $(2i+1)2^{-j}$ is $q_{2n}$ for some $n\leqslant2^j$ hence, for each of these indexes $n$, $(2n)^2(q_{2n}-x)^2\leqslant4$. For these specific enumerations, the series asked about in the question diverges, for every $x$.

On the other hand, one can decide that, for some specified $x$, $|q_n-x|\geqslant n^{-1/4}$ for every $n$, then the series converges. Likewise, for every finite set $X$, one can choose an enumeration $(q_n)$ such that the series converges, for every $x$ in $X$.

Comment: If I understand your proof correctly, it still works if you replace, $n^2$ by $n^3$ in the series, right? All it changes is that $(2n)^3(q_{2n}-x)^{2}\leq Cn$, which still gives divergence for all $x$. That is a bit puzzling to me, as I am pretty convinced that if we replace $n^2$ by $n^{2+\delta}$, we get converge a.e. on $(0,1)$. I must be missing something.

Comment: The mistake you are doing is a bit subtle: note that the upper bound $\Theta(n)$ is valid, not for every $n$ but for those $n$ such that $q_{2n}$ is close to $x$, that is, roughly one $n$ in every slice $(2^j,2^{j+1})$. Thus the series $\sum\limits1/n$ over these indexes $n$ converges.

Comment: I see! Thank you. I was hoping to get something (just one $x$, not necessarily a.e. convergence) for $n^2$, but I see this is impossible in general. I understand your last paragraph, but can it be improved? Can we find some enumeration of rationals such that we get a.e. convergence on $(0,1)$ for $n^2$?